# How to make getopts parameter optional

Tags: bash, script, shell-script, automation, bash-scripting

I wrote [the following](https://github.com/Kaos-Industries/cigs.sh/blob/main/cigs.sh) `bash` script as a budgeting tool to more accurately calculate (and moderate) when I last bought a pack of cigarettes.

In addition to `-h` for printing the output, it takes one other option: `-b` with (what is intended to be) an optional parameter to set the offset in hours. So `-b 5` logs a new pack of cigs bought 5 hours ago, and subsequent runs of `cigs.sh` indicate how many weeks, days or hours it's been since then. If the elapsed time since the last time I bought a pack is less than `$threshold`, the output is printed in red; if the elapsed time is more than `$threshold`, the output is green, indicating it's now "okay" for me to buy a new pack.

I've managed to get all this working fine except for one thing: it's currently not possible to specify `-b` *without* an offset (i.e. log the purchase as being made right now instead of some hours into the past). As far as I've been able to tell this seems to be a limitation of `getopts`: without the colon in `b:h`, $OPTARG fails to populate causing the logic in the `b)` case option to fail; with the colon, it prevents `-b` from being used without a parameter, throwing the following error:

> /usr/local/bin/scripts/cigs.sh: option requires an argument -- b
> Unknown parameter passed: -b

Here is the `getopts` portion of my script:

```
while getopts "b:h" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
    h)
        echo "$usage"
        exit
        ;;
    b)
        offset=$OPTARG
        if [[ -n $offset && ! $offset =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then 
        echo "HOURS parameter passed to -b must be an integer."
        exit
        fi
        echo -e "Bought a new $item...\nResetting timer to 0 days and $offset hours."
        offset=$((offset*60*60))
        last_bought="$(date -u +%s)"
        new_lb=$((last_bought-offset))
        echo $new_lb > $lb_file
        exit
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Happy to help you! But link your code in the repo is broken. Seems like all that is left is this: https://github.com/Kaos-Industries/cigs.sh

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Yes I deleted the original file and am planning to re-upload the latest version with your changes (and credit to you) as soon as I've implemented another change I'm working on.

Comment: Sounds good! Just remember to not leave dead links in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting issue here. Based on what I understand about how `getopts` works, this use of a single colon (`:`) means that the option value must be set:

```
getopts "b:h"
```

And if you wanted it to be optional, you would need to set two colons (`::`) and also have nothing follow that like this:

```
getopts "hb::"
```

But that `hb::` doesn’t work.

I played around with your script and this is the only solution I could get to work. It changes your `getopts "b:h"` to be `getopts "bh"` so both option parameters are optional. But the magic is in adding more code to the `b)` case so the whole `while` chunk now looks like this:

```
while getopts "bh" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
    h)
        echo "$usage"
        exit
        ;;
    b)
        eval nextopt=\${$OPTIND}
        if [[ -n $nextopt && $nextopt != -* ]] ; then
        OPTIND=$((OPTIND + 1))
        offset=$nextopt
        else
        offset=0
        fi
        if [[ -n $offset && ! $offset =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "HOURS parameter passed to -b must be an integer."
        exit
        fi
        echo -e "Bought a new $item...\nResetting timer to 0 days and $offset hours."
        offset=$((offset*60*60))
        last_bought="$(date -u +%s)"
        new_lb=$((last_bought-offset))
        echo $new_lb > $lb_file
        exit
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

The magic comes from this chunk over here that is [based on this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697692/117259) to a question about the same issue:

```
# Check next positional parameter
eval nextopt=\${$OPTIND}
# existing or starting with dash?
if [[ -n $nextopt && $nextopt != -* ]] ; then
OPTIND=$((OPTIND + 1))
offset=$nextopt
```

Clearly not as clean as what would be expect if the `getopts "hb::"` worked, but it doesn’t so this kludge works.

If anyone else more experienced with Bash can explain why — or come up with a cleaner solution — they should post it. For now, this works so it works!

Comment: I had to do some rearranging to get the logic to work, which I also made to your `while` chunk, but aside from that this works perfectly. I had a feeling the answer I was looking for was somewhere in the linked question but couldn't for the life of me figure out how to apply the answers to my own `while` loop, so thank you.